# How are Qt signals/slots actually coupled to the elements in a .ui file?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm currently working on a Qt project and am somewhat confused with the signals and slots mechanism. I feel however that I have a somewhat good understanding between the differences between a QObject and user interface form.

A user interface form (described by a .ui file) is fed into the user interface compiler(uic) and produces an associated header file. This header file doesn't just contain interface information, but instead contains the implementation details on a QObject should be formatted. A QObject on the other hand is the base class in which a lot of the Qt framework is built upon. The signals and slot systems is based completely on the QObject.

When extending the QObject class (or from a derived class), you are actually defining an object in which can produce signals and slots. To format this object to look like the user interface you just designed in Qt Designer, you create an instance of the ui class (via the ui header generated by the uic). You call the setup method on this class and feed it the new QObject you're creating.

This all seems to make sense.

However, what doesn't make sense is when you start actually defining signals. From with Qt Designer, I have the option to right click and select a 'signal'. When I select a signal (whether that be a mouse click on a button or a change in a progress bar), it ends up adding that to my QObjects signals section. My question is: why and how? How exactly are my actions in Qt Designer (a program that generates an XML for the uic) getting coupled to my QObject in Qt Creator? More specifically, how does it know which QObject to add this slot to?

This question may be somewhat unclear, so I'll throw an example here.

Say for example I want to create a new interactive display of some kind. Let's call it 'MyScreen'. In order to create this interface, I would likely have 3 files: 'myscreen.h', 'myscreen.cpp', and 'myscreen.ui'.  'myscreen.h' is responsible for declaring the QObjects properties and methods as well as signals and slots. 'myscreen.cpp' is responsible for defining the methods, signals, and slots. 'myscreen.ui' is repsonible for creating the user interface layout that will be used to format an instance of MyScreen.

But due to what I had stated previously saying that the ui is just used for generating a header, why exactly is it coupled to 'myscreen.cpp'? That is, I can right click on the .ui layout, create a new signal type, and that signal type will be added to the myscreen.h and myscreen.cpp. How does this happen? How is  it coupled? Does Qt operate such that there should always be 3 files (xxx.h, xxx.cpp, xxx.ui) that should exist?

So hopefully that gives you some context in what I'm confused about. There doesn't seem to be a well written document (that I've found at least), that thoroughly describes the underlying relationship between all these items.

TLDR - How does the signal/slot from the .h and .cpp actually link to the elements defined in the .ui file?

Comment: Compile it and inspect your output folder. It generates a file with code.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> My question is: why and how? How exactly are my actions in Qt Designer (a program that generates an XML for the uic) getting coupled to my QObject in Qt Creator? More specifically, how does it know which QObject to add this slot to?

The short answer is: magic.

The real answer is, it actually has nothing to do with your actions in Designer, at least not directly. It's not actually even a UI-specific thing, it's just that designer makes good use of it. What happens is this:

First of all, any time you compile a file that makes use of the `Q_OBJECT` macro, this triggers Qt's `moc` tool to run during compilation ("triggers" isn't really the most accurate description: More precisely, when `qmake` is run to generate makefiles, it adds build rules to run `moc` when `Q_OBJECT` is detected in a header, but that's beside the point). Details are a bit outside the scope of this answer but long story short is it ultimately generates those `moc_*.cpp` files you'll see after compilation, which contain a whole bunch of compiled meta info. The important part of this is where it generates run-time accessible information about the various signals and slots you have declared. You'll see how that's important here below.

The other important thing is all `QObject`s have [a name](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qobject.html#objectName-prop). This name is accessible at runtime. *The name you give your widgets in designer is set as the widget's object name.* The reason this is important will also become clear below.

And the final important thing is `QObject`s have a hierarchical structure; when you create a `QObject` you can set its parent. All of the widgets on your form ultimately have the form itself (e.g. your `QMainWindow`-derived class) as their parent.

Ok, so...

You'll notice in source code Qt generates for your windows you always have that `ui->setupUi(this)` call in the constructor. The implementation of that function is generated by Qt's `uic` tool during compilation, in e.g. `ui_mainwindow.h`. That function is where all the properties you set up in designer, stored in the .ui file, are actually set, including the widgets' object names. Now, the last line of the generated `setupUI()` implementation is the key:

```
void setupUi(QMainWindow *MainWindow) {
    ...
    // Object properties, including names, are set here. This is 
    // generated from the .ui file. For example:
    pushButton = new QPushButton(centralWidget);
    pushButton->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("pushButton"));
    pushButton->setGeometry(QRect(110, 70, 75, 23));
    ...
    // This is the important part for the signal/slot binding:
    QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName(MainWindow);
}
```

That function, [`connectSlotsByName`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmetaobject.html#connectSlotsByName), is where the magic happens for all those widget signals.

Basically that function does the following:

1. Iterate through all your declared slot names, which it can do because this was all packed into runtime-accessible strings by `moc` in the meta object info.
2. When it finds a slot whose name matches the pattern `on_<objectname>_<signalname>`, it recursively searches the object hierarchy for an object whose name is *<objectname>*, e.g. one of your named widgets, or whatever other named objects you may have created. It then connects that objects signal, *<signalname>* to the slot it found (it basically automates calls to `QObject::connect(...)`).

And that's it.

So what this means is, nothing special actually happens in designer when you go to a slot there. *All that happens is designer inserts a slot named on_widgetName_signalName, with the appropriate parameters, into your header and generates an empty function body for it.* (thuga has added [a great explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39201445/616460) of this). This is enough for `QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName` to find it at run time and set up the connection.

The implications here are very convenient:

- You can remove a widget's signal handler without doing anything special in designer. You just remove the slot and its definition from your source file, it's all completely self contained.
- You can add widget signal handlers by hand without having to go through the designer interface, which can save you some tedium sometimes. All you have to do is create a slot in your window named e.g. `on_lineEdit1_returnPressed()` and voila, it works. You just have to be careful, as hyde reminds us in a comment: If you make a mistake here you won't get a compile-time error, you will only get a run-time warning printed to stderr and the connection won't be created; so it's important to pay attention to console output if you make any changes here.

The other implication here is that this functionality isn't actually limited to UI components. `moc` runs for all your `QObject`s, and `connectSlotsByName` is always available. So any object hierarchy you create, if you name the objects, then declare slots with appropriate names, you can call `connectSlotsByName` to automatically set up connections; it just so happens that `uic` sticks that call at the end of `setupUi`, because that's a convenient place to put it. But the magic isn't UI-specific, and doesn't rely on `uic`, only on the meta info. It's a generally available mechanism. It's pretty neat.

As an aside: I stuck a quick example of `QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName` on [GitHub](https://github.com/JC3/QtNamedSlotExample).

Comment: Ah, ok, good to know! Looks like I haven't made typos with it then ;)  Removed my wrong comment. Then note about watching for run time errors is good, then.

Comment: @hyde *"Looks like I haven't made typos with it then"* - Yeah... me, on the other hand, I see "no matching signal" scroll across my eyelids when I go to bed at night. :(

Comment: With explicit old style connects they were common enough for me too (lesson: use Qt Creator to autocomplete SIGNAL/SLOT macros), so I know what you're talking about...

Comment: It's a nice example, but boy oh boy it's so verbose as to be nearly incomprehensible. I'd put everything into a single `main.cpp` ending with `#include <main.moc>`, and show the source in the answer itself. It'll be below 50 lines long, it'll display even without the vertical scrollbar. Rationale: You're not writing an enterprise project. Anything less than a thousand lines usually belongs in one source file anyway, otherwise you're wasting lots of effort on a multi-file form that's completely unhelpful for understanding.

Comment: @KubaOber It's a quick example put together in under 5 minutes, it's completely representative, it's organized like what anybody using Qt Creator to create projects would be familiar with, and it's got like a whopping dozen lines of actual code in it ("enterprise project" sized, I know), all in example.cpp. And it's not getting pasted into the answer, because it's just a distracting (as evidenced by your comment) sidenote that I added this morning. If that's too verbose or "incomprehensible" for you or somehow distracts from all the actual info here, I don't know what to tell you, lol.

Comment: It's an example of the use of `connectSlotsByName`, not an example of how an [outdated & atrocious] Qt Creator project template might look. Precisely because there's a whopping dozen lines of code in it, it belongs all in one file, so that it's concise. No need for `QCoreApplication` instance, too. I of course exaggerate in calling it "incomprehensible" :) Anyway, I've forked it and morphed it into [something else](https://github.com/KubaO/QtNamedSlotExample/blob/master/main.cpp) that uses more modern by-value C++11 approach and explicitly tests it.

Comment: (@KubaOber The purpose is also to show how Designer's code modifications tie in to the UI element signal / slot connections, an important point that's been unfortunately discarded in your new example!)

Comment: @KubaOber I found the response to be very helpful and completely comprehensible.

Comment: @JasonC Referencing this well done post again. I'm curious, how did you actually learn all of this? It doesn't appear that Qt publishes any type of full walkthrough of this. Did you just gain this knowledge your experiences with Qt?

Answer (score 8):

What happens when you add a slot from the `Go to slot...` context menu item, is it goes through your project, and it looks for any files that include `ui_myclass.h`. When it finds this file, it then makes sure that `Ui::MyClass` object is declared either in that file, or in directly included files. These would be your `myclass.cpp` and `myclass.h` files. If it finds these files, it will then add the slot declaration and the definition in those files.

You can test this by removing the `Ui::MyClass` object (*usually named `ui`*) declaration from your `myclass.h` file, and then adding a slot by using the `Go to slot...` function in the designer. You should get some error message stating it couldn't find `Ui::MyClass` object declaration. 
You can also try removing the `ui_myclass.h` inclusion from your `myclass.cpp` file. If you try adding a slot from the designer now, you will get an error message stating that it couldn't find `ui_myclass.h` included anywhere, or something like that.

If you define everything just inside your `myclass.h` file and remove `myclass.cpp`, it should give you an error message stating that it is unable to add the slot definition.

You can inspect how it works in more detail by looking at [this part of the source code](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qt-creator/src/plugins/designer/qtcreatorintegration.cpp.html#504).

But in the end what really matters is, that you declare and define your class methods in separate `.h` and `.cpp` files, and that `ui_xxx.h` is included and that `Ui::xxx` object has been declared in those files. Of course this is what Qt Creator does for you automatically when you add a new form class, so you don't have to worry about it.